# Array or Json to String

Tags: php, arrays, json

change the string to array is

```php
$string = '[{"name":"jack","address":"who knows"},{"name":"jill","address":"who knows too"}]';

$array = json_decode($array,true);
```

but what if it's reversed change array to string

```php
$array = [{"name":"jack","address":"who knows"},{"name":"jill","address":"who knows too"}];

$string = $array; // $string is $string like on first example
```

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as:

```
$string = '[{"name":"jack","address":"who knows"},{"name":"jill","address":"who knows too"}]';
$array = json_decode($string,true); // convert string -> array
$string = json_encode($array); // convert array -> string 
echo $string; // will output the original string
```

Comment: wow thank you so much
RIP 6 hours